# Trying to add scroll animation to my website

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to add this animation *(on codepen)* to a website. I can seem to get it to show up. Alone it works fine but when i try to add it to my website it wont show. I would like it to be in the middle at the bottom of the background image.

Here is the **[codepen](https://codepen.io/2xsamurai/pen/WwmjKQ)**

Here is my **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ac4d72uy/)**

```
<div class="scroll-downs">
<div class="mousey">
<div class="scroller"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I think my problem might be the location of where i put the html code for the animation but i tried everywhere and cant get it to work.

I added a background image from web so you guys can see.

Comment: It appears you forgot to copy in the relevant CSS classes in the fiddle. You will need both html and css code to make this animation work.

Comment: This seems centered [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbLwv3cn/#&togetherjs=p6ftdJFh45)

Comment: I didnt add it to the fiddle since i couldnt get it working. and not sure what you mean @iSZ

Comment: I do see it now my bad @iSZ how could i get it placed at the bottom of the screen and scale it down a bit

Comment: Right now its only showing up in that jsfiddle. On mine with my bg image its not showing at all still. I thought it might be behind the image but i gave them z-index and its still not showing.

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove You are probably best of set position fixed on scroll-downs or position:absolute and the parent to relative and it should work. Also set position relative on .mousey and then an offset in top to move it down the page.

Comment: I gave a position absolute to .scroll-downs. and position relative to .mousey and it still doesnt seem to work

Comment: you probably need to add min-height:100vw to the container and set it to relative.

Comment: heres what i changed, still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/bfw9kf2b/

Comment: The .scroller shouldn't have min-height 100vw in it. You need to make sure the overlay html is just under the body tag and make sure you have html{height:100%} and body{min-height:100%; height:auto} set to make sure your body is higher enough to center the element in. Looks cool by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `fixed` to the overlay to keep the scroll icon in place and maybe hide it on scroll

```css
.scroll-downs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width :34px;
  height: 55px;
}
.mousey {
  width: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.scroller {
  width: 3px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 25%;
  background-color: #000;
  animation-name: scroll;
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.15,.41,.69,.94);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  10% { transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1; }
  100% { transform: translateY(15px); opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-downs">
  <div class="mousey">
    <div class="scroller"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```